# "SSL handshake failed" error for Let's Encrypt on September 2021

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, qtquick2, lets-encrypt

I developed a cross-platform application using Qt and QtQuick technology. Communication with backend server is secured by Let's Encrypt SSL.
But in September 2021 the Qt app starts to report "SSL handshake failed" error without any change in client or server.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

After some research, I find out the reason:

https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

> DST Root CA X3 will expire on September 30, 2021. That means those older devices that don’t trust ISRG Root X1 will start getting certificate warnings when visiting sites that use Let’s Encrypt certificates.

So, I have to add ISRG Root X1 certificate manually into my app's trusted CA database. In order to achieve that, I visited the Let's Encrypt site using FireFox and saved the ISRG Root X1 certificate PEM file into my application resource (into `qrc` file). Then I added that into the default CA certificate database using the following code:

```cpp
//Adding CA root certificate of the Let'sEncrypt into default CA DB
//for Qt 5.15+
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 15, 0)
qDebug() << "loading embedded \"ISRG Root X1\" CA cert:" << QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration().addCaCertificates(":/ca_certs/isrg_root_x1.pem");
#else
qDebug() << "loading embedded \"ISRG Root X1\" CA cert:" << QSslSocket::addDefaultCaCertificates(":/ca_certs/isrg_root_x1.pem");
#endif
```

Note that there is a new way to do this for Qt 5.15+ while the old way is deprecated. I used Qt 5.12, so I need to add both ways (in order to make my app more ready for Qt 5.15+), as you can see.

Thanks to Qt's good architecture, you don't need to do any more change.